# iOS App starts but is always terminated immediately before app opens

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When trying to start an app in debug mode from Visual Studio on a real iOS 10 device, VS will display "Launching app", and then immediately follow up with an "App terminated" message.

No detailed error can be found in the device logs.

I have tried several things, including deleting caches, restarting, reconnecting, rebooting devices and Mac Agent.

I have followed this bug issue to clear caches (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43239) but with no success.

Also I made sure that all entitlements are correctly described.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation it turns out that XCode was displaying a tiny message, that this version of XCode was incompatible with the device.

This message is not carried through to Visual Studio.

**Update XCode!**

Second, possible solution from the bug tracker (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43239):

Delete contents of 
`%AppData%\Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch\` on windows machine
`$HOME/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA` on mac machine

Hope this saves somebody else some time.